# In an aspx file where does the actual code gets loaded?

Tags: asp.net, class, inheritance

So this code is in a file `login.aspx` which literally has some html mnarkup and the below code, so where does this code get loaded from? Where is the *App_Web_login.aspx.d7a6dcf1* file located ?

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="stadm_login, 
         App_Web_login.aspx.d7a6dcf1" enableeventvalidation="false" theme="Niko" %>
```

Comment: The file does not exist on the server. The code is compiled into a library.

Comment: Look for `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET/xxx/Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Comment: What does that inherits="stadm_login, 
         App_Web_login.aspx.d7a6dcf1".  Means ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is contained in a file that is associated with its page. In Visual Studio if you load the project you will see a caret next to the aspx page. Click that and you will see a file associated with that page. That is the code file, or code behind, for the login page.

When the project is built, the code for each page is wrapped into a dll file or code package for the entire project. What you see for the inherits in the page is the base class for the project and also the inheriting of the page class.

So if my project is called FooProject, then at the top of each page where it says inherits, you will something like this (the _base class .page class):

```
inherits=_FooProject.Login
```

Comment: Whats the project ?I got cpanel access to my newly assigned server of my company.And there is a file in management of blog directory login.aspx that has this.Where can I get the project ?

Comment: The project itself is probably stored on a separate server such as a Team Foundation Server. To view all the files for the app you are dealing with, do a search for the login page and within that file's location will be the rest of the files you are trying to view or edit. Please note that the folder that contains the login page will have a file folder called bin. In that folder is a dll file that contains the entire code for the app you are trying manage.